# How to insert github source code to my project

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I'm new at GitHub. I found a library that I want to use in my Android project ([Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)), but I don't know how.
After downloading the source code I'm stuck with a zip folder that I don't know how to import it into my project. I'm working with Android Studio.

Any help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip the downloaded project. Open YOUR project in Android studio. Click File -> Import module. Add this module as a dependency to your project. You should be good to go.

**[EDIT]**

BUT, since Glide has gradle/maven support, I can just simply modify your project's *build.gradle* file and add the following lines to the *dependencies* group:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.3.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0' // You might need to increase the version numbers if the libraries have never versions
```

Comment: Hey @Mike its telling me that Gradle project sync failed : "Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'robolectric' not found."

Comment: roboelectric is a dependency that Glide has. Please check Glide's gradle file and change the plugin's version number in line the
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.12.+'    Probably it should be increased

Comment: Why not just use Gradle and add this to your dependencies? compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.3.+'

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't notice it's on mavencentral. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Where is the "Import Module" selection in the file tab? I don't see it in Windows 10 on the latest version of Android studio..